# Error al hacer una petición UPDATE en API Rest NodeJS con Express y MySQL2

Tags: nodejs, api, rest

Soy principiante en API Rest NodeJS con Express y MySQL. Estoy creando la petición Update desde Postman para actualizar un registro de línea de la base de datos  creada en MySQL WorkBench y la consola me envía el siguiente error cuando envío la petición:

> ***Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( name, price, stock, description, status) SET ( 'Limón', 2450, 123,'variedad C' at line 1****

Ya revisé la documentación y no encuentro el error en la Sintaxis.

```js
        const { response, request } = require("express");
        const express = require("express");
        const app = express();
        const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");
        const port = 3001;
    const bluebird = require("bluebird");
    
    let connection; //Variable para almacenar la conexión a la DB
    
    //Configura el servidor para recibir dtos en formato Json
    app.use(express.json());
    
    app.get("/get-products", async(request, response) => {
        const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute("SELECT * FROM products");
    
        console.log(rows);
        console.log(fields.length);
        response.send("Todo ok");
    });
    
    /* app.get("/get-product/:id"), async (request, response) => {
        await connection.execute("SELECT*FROM products WHERE id= ?", [request.params.id]);
        console.log()
        response.send("el ID de empleado");
    
    } */
    
    app.post("/add-product", async(request, response) => {
        const product = request.body;
        const name = product.name;
        const price = product.price;
        const stock = product.stock;
        const description = product.description;
        const status = product.status;
    
    
        await connection.execute(`INSERT INTO products(name, price, stock, description, status) VALUES ('${name}', ${price}, ${stock},'${description}', '${status}')`);
    
        console.log(product);
        response.json(product);
    
        /*   /* /* Se convierten en variable   de una función utilizando la destructuración*/
    });
    
    app.put("/update-product/id", async(request, response) => {
        let {
            id
        } = request.params;
    
        const product = request.body;
    
        const name = product.name;
        const price = product.price;
        const stock = product.stock;
        const description = product.description;
        const status = product.status;
    
        await connection.execute(`UPDATE products( name, price, stock, description, status) SET ( '${name}', ${price}, ${stock},'${description}', '${status}') WHERE ('${id}') `);
    
    
      
        console.log(product.name);
        response.json(product);
    })
    
    
    
        console.log(product.name);
        response.json(product);
    });
    
    app.listen(port, async() => {
        connection = await mysql.createConnection({
            host: "localhost",
            user: "root",
            port: 3306,
            password: "root",
            database: "tienda-grupo-23",
            Promise: bluebird,
        });
        console.log("Server running on port: " + port);
    });
```

Comment: Revisa esto: `WHERE ('${id}')`. No hay una comparación para esa cláusula `WHERE`. Tal vez lo que deseas poner es `WHERE (id='${id}')`. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por su interés. La solución sugerida no resolvió el error. He estado revisando de nuevo y veo que  Let {id}  según el VSC me indica  let id: string cuando id es number.

Answer (score 1):

Las sentencias `UPDATE` no son similares a las sentencias `INSERT`. Es lo que parece que has interpretado al escribir esto:

```
await connection.execute(`UPDATE products( name, price, stock, description, status) SET ( '${name}', ${price}, ${stock},'${description}', '${status}') WHERE ('${id}') `);
```

Las sentencias `UPDATE`  deben tener la siguiente sintaxis:

```
UPDATE laTabla
SET
    unaColumnaAlfanumerica = 'unValorAlfanumerico',
    unaColumnaNumerica = unValorNumerico,
    unaColumnaBooleana = unValorBooleano 
WHERE laColumnaCriterio = elValorCriterio
```

NÓTESE que en las columnas alfanuméricas se usan comillas simples para los valores, no así en las columnas numéricas o booleanas.

Intenta de este modo, si alguna columna no es alfanumérica, retira las comillas simples que rodea los valores:

```
await connection.execute(`UPDATE products SET name='${name}', price='${price}', stock='${stock}', description='${description}', status='${status}' WHERE id='${id}'`);
```

OJO: Aquí he asumido que tu columna de ID se llama `id`, si se llama de otro modo lo cambias en `WHERE id`  y si esa columna es del tipo numérico puedes quitar las comillas simples que rodean el valor.

Para más detalles sobre las sentencias `UPDATE` consulta el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html).

#### Nota sobre la seguridad

Tu consulta es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Deberías corregir ese grave error de seguridad usando consultas preparadas u otro método garantizado por Node.

Comment: Gracias por su interés. La solución sugerida no resolvió el error. He estado revisando de nuevo y veo que  Let {id}  según el VSC me indica  let id: string cuando id es number.

Comment: @Íkio el error planteado en la pregunta es un error de sintaxis, causado por una sentencia UPDATE mal escrita. Si una vez resuelto ese problema surge otro, entonces tendrás que garantizar que el tipo de dato sea el correcto, aunque no entiendo bien en tu comentario a qué te refieres: ¿la columna `id` en la base de datos es numérica? ¿el tipo de dato de la variable es string y debería ser numérico?. Yo no uso Node, por lo que no podría decirte más. De todos modos, esto tendría que ver con el problema de seguridad que refiero al final de la respuesta, deberías usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: Buen día A. Cedano.

Comment: Buen día.  Agradezco sus respuesta. Ya funcionó con la primera instrucción que referenció. Sólo hacia falta una  (').